# TableView rows won't carry data into new section

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm a retired high school teacher putting together a chemistry app that will include my online videos.  I've gotten as far as creating a table with sections that link to a web view page...pretty successful except for one thing:  the first cell row that occurs in sections after the first section (called Compounds and Reactions) will not link to their proper video, but will bring up the first video in the first section again.  And the second row in the new section will bring up the second video in the first section, etc. (For example: the Periodic Table video comes up no problem when selected under the section Compounds and Reactions, but it also comes up when I select Hydrates under the Stoichiometry section)  I'm convinced I don't have the right code for this part (cell!.textLabel?.text = sectionData[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]) from the code below,  but I'm not sure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated to this novice.  Cheers!

```
import UIKit

class CompoundsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let sections: [String] = ["Compounds and Reactions", "Stoichiometry"]
    let s1Data: [String] = ["Periodic Table", "Molecules", "Ionic Compounds","Polyatomic Ions"]
    let s2Data: [String] = ["Hydrates", "Acids"]

    var sectionData: [Int: [String]] = [:]




    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var videos:[Video] = [Video]()
    var selectedVideo:Video?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let model = VideoModel()
        self.videos = model.getVideos()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        sectionData = [0 : s1Data, 1 : s2Data]
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return (sectionData[section]?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]

    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell");
        }


        //Customize the cell to display the video title
        cell!.textLabel?.text = sectionData[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.selectedVideo = self.videos[indexPath.row]

        //Took note of which video the viewer selected
        //Call the segue
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let detailViewController = segue.destination as! VideoDetailViewController

        detailViewController.selectedVideo = self.selectedVideo
    }

}
```

Comment: How is `videos` related to the table view data (which is actually `[Int: [String]]`)? You get always the same video in each section because the section parameter is not considered. I recommend a custom struct as data source.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to say if for example `indexPath.section` is equal to 0 get data from first array and in this array when for example `indexPath.row` is equal to 1 get second item in this array. To achieve this, you can create array of arrays.

```
var videos = [["Periodic Table", "Molecules", "Ionic Compounds","Polyatomic Ions"], ["Hydrates", "Acids"]]
```

So in TableView delegate method you can get array depends on section index and item in this array depends on row index:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedVideo = self.videos[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: self)
}
```

Alternatively, you can create your custom data model.